# Is it better complexity wise to use the map() function in python or a comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time-complexity, space-complexity

As the question states. 
map(f, iterable) can be written as [f(x) for x in iterable].
Which is better to use? And why?

As an example,
I would like to convert a list of strings to int.

```
ip = (raw_input().split())
ip = [int(x) for x in ip]
```

or

```
ip = (raw_input().split())
ip = map(int, ip)
```

Comment: Found the link: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196 where Guido van Rossum explains why he wanted to drop `map`, `filter`, `lambda` and `reduce` from the language.

Comment: When you say "complexity", are you talking about the computer science concept (big-O notation)? Or do you mean "complexity of code"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I meant the computer science concept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map may be microscopically faster in some cases (when you're NOT making a lambda for the purpose, but using the same function in map and a listcomp). List comprehensions may be faster in other cases and most (not all) pythonistas consider them more direct and clearer.

more clearly explained here [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)

Comment: Since you're only copying the first paragraph of Alex Martelli's answer you linked to, it would have been more appropriate to suggest closing the question as a duplicate. Not sure if your reputation is sufficient to do that, so I did it for you. Thanks for finding the canonical answer!

Comment: I didn't know that, recently started answering here. Will check that out. Thanks.